# Callback returns undefined with chrome.storage.sync.get

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension

I'm building a Chrome extension and I wrote this code.

```
var Options = function(){};

Options.prototype = {

    getMode: function(){
               return chrome.storage.sync.get("value", function(e){  
                 console.log(e); // it prints 'Object {value: "test"}'.       
                 return e;
               });
    },

    setMode: function(){
        chrome.storage.sync.set({"value": "test"}, function(e) {         
        })
    }
}

var options = new Options();
options.setMode();
console.log(options.getMode()); // it prints 'undefined'.
```

I expected it to print

```
Object {value: "set up"}
```

when I call `options.getMode()`, but it prints `undefined`.

Does anyone know how to fix this problem?

Comment: @Qantas94Heavy so, it's not possible to receive it at all?

Comment: Not in the way you have done it in the second example, no.

Answer (score 23, accepted):

The [`chrome.storage`](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/storage) API is [asynchronous](https://stackoverflow.com/q/14220321/2074608) - it doesn't return it directly, rather passing it as an argument to the callback function. The function call itself always returns `undefined`.

This is often used to allow other methods to run without having to wait until something responds or completes - an example of this is `setTimeout` (only difference is that it returns a timer value, not `undefined`).

For example, take this:

```
setTimeout(function () { alert(1); }, 10000);
alert(0);
```

Because `setTimeout` is asynchronous, it will not stop all code until the entire function completes, rather returning initially, only calling a function when it is completed later on - this is why 0 comes up before 1.

---

For this reason, you **cannot** simply do something like:

```
// "foo" will always be undefined
var foo = asyncBar(function (e) { return e; });
```

Generally, you should put what you want to do in your callback (the function that is called when the asynchronous function is completed). This is a fairly common way of writing asynchronous code:

```
function getValue(callback) {
  chrome.storage.sync.get("value", callback);
}
```

You could place an entire portion of your code inside the callback - there's nothing stopping you from doing so. So instead of doing the following:

```
console.log(getValue()); // typical synchronous method of doing something
```

This would probably be a better idea:

```
// how it would be done in asynchronous code
getValue(function (value) {
  console.log(value);
});
```

Comment: >this is why 0 comes up before 1. 
I see. Thanks!! It's very clear.

Comment: >var foo;
>asyncBar(function (e) { foo = e; });

I think I tried something like this. But, I'll try it again now!

Comment: I tried this code. But, it returns undefined at the end of code in the post.                var test;
               chrome.storage.sync.get("value", function(e){  
                 console.log(e);      
                 test = e;
               });

Comment: This is the whole code without setMode(). var Options = function(){};
Options.prototype = {
    getMode: function(){

               var test;               

               chrome.storage.sync.get("value", function(e){  
                 console.log(e); 
                 test = e;
                 return test;
               });

    }

}

var options = new Options();
console.log(options.getMode());

Comment: @crzyonez777: I seem to have misled you.  That still wouldn't work for the same reasons I have outlined above - that was meant for if you were to use that (much) later somewhere else, `test` would still be undefined and return out of the function straight after that call.

Comment: so, this doesn't work either. var Options = function(){};
Options.prototype = {
    getMode: function(callback){    

               chrome.storage.sync.get("value", callback);

    }

}

var options = new Options();

var test = options.getMode(function (e) { return e; });
console.log(test);

Comment: So, I should give up wrapping it with getter method.

Comment: so, I should define methods that doesn't return anything if I use asynchronous callback.

Comment: @crzyonez777: well any return value isn't likely to have much effect, so (basically) yes.

Comment: So `localStorage` is synchronous and `chorme.storage` is asynchronous. What a nightmare if you're targeting both browser and chrome app. In my situation the UI updates before the settings are obtained from `chrome.storage`, so I must update the UI again in the callback!

Comment: Can you use 'await' to fix this?

Comment: Maybe there isn't a valid value yet ?

Answer (score 10):

[Chrome storage API](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/storage) is asynchronous and it uses `callback`, that's why you're getting this behavior.

You can use `Promise` API to overcome this asynchronous issue, which is simpler and cleaner. Here is an example:

```
async function getLocalStorageValue(key) {
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        try {
            chrome.storage.sync.get(key, function (value) {
                resolve(value);
            })
        }
        catch (ex) {
            reject(ex);
        }
    });
}

const result = await getLocalStorageValue("my-key");
```

Comment: Keep in mind that the `value` in that function is an object and if you want to get exactly the _value_ of the requested key you should use `resolve(value[key]);` instead of `resolve(value);`

Comment: Thank you. One snarky comment towards Google devs: Was it a good idea to name an **async** method literally **sync**? Who would ever guess…

Answer (score 2):

The `chrome.storage.sync.get` is called asynchronously, that's why you have to pass it a callback, so that it is executed in the future.

When you try to print the returned value of `getMode`you are printing the return value of whatever `chrome.storage.sync.get` returns after queuing the asynchronous call to be executed.

This is a common mistake people do in javascript, while they are learning to use asynch calls.

Comment: Thank you very much. I got it. But, how can I get the value by getter method?

Comment: You can't return it. You need to pass a callback into the method.

Comment: so, I shouldn't wrap callback function with getter method since callback is asynchronous and getter is synchronous.