# Google Chrome extension Storage no value

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension, google-chrome-devtools

I am trying to update my Javascript knowledge,

At the moment I am currently developing a Google Chrome extension, I tried to save some information in the local storage, but of course, the data is deleted after close the browser.

I thought in use chrome.storage however for some stupid reason, is not working (manifiest file edited with storage permissions provided)

here my example code :

```
chrome.storage.local.set({"SRSaved": "ASDASD"}, function(){});
chrome.storage.local.get("SRSaved", function(result){idList = result;});
```

If inside the getter function I print the value of result, is a object and the data is there, ok, however the idList value is undefined, is strange, and , of course idList is declared before

Someone can bring me some light with this problem?

Comment: You are aware that `result` is `{"SRSaved": "ASDASD"}`?  Other than that, I'm not seeing what may be off.  Could you post more of your code?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Callback returns undefined with chrome.storage.sync.get](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18699075/callback-returns-undefined-with-chrome-storage-sync-get)

Comment: BTW, just googled the exact title of the question and got another answer in top-5 results.

Comment: there are hundreds of similar dups about async code

Comment: possible duplicate of [Why is my variable unaltered after I modify it inside of a function? - Asynchronous code reference](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23667086/why-is-my-variable-unaltered-after-i-modify-it-inside-of-a-function-asynchron)