# There is a bug in my Chrome Extension

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension

There is a bug in my Chrome extension which I can't solve.
When a user submits data upon installation of the extension, it is stored with chrome.storage.sync.set(). When the user clicks the 'Compose' button in Gmail, the content script sends a message, to which the entered data is sent in a response. The first time I load Gmail, the data returns 'undefined'. The only way I have been able to fix it is by adding 'alert();' into my code. It's really inconvenient and I cannot find any other ways to fix it.

background.js

```
var name, title, company, email, photo, phone;

chrome.runtime.onConnect.addListener(function(port) {
  console.assert(port.name == "knockknock");
  port.onMessage.addListener(function(msg) {


      chrome.storage.sync.get("name",function(data){
         name = data.name; 
      });

      chrome.storage.sync.get("title",function(data){
         title = data.title; 
      });

      chrome.storage.sync.get("company",function(data){
         company = data.company; 
      });

      chrome.storage.sync.get("email",function(data){
         email = data.email; 
      });

      chrome.storage.sync.get("photo",function(data){
         photo = data.photo; 
      });

      chrome.storage.sync.get("phone",function(data){
         phone = data.phone; 
      });

      alert();

    if (msg.reason == "getInfo"){

        port.postMessage({name: name, title: title, company: company, email: email, photo: photo, phone: phone});

    }
  });
});
```

setup.js (This is where data is initially entered)

```
 $('.ee-required').slideUp(400,function(){
                $('.ee-form-saved').slideDown();
                var name = document.getElementsByClassName('ee-form-name')[0].value;
                var title = document.getElementsByClassName('ee-form-title')[0].value;
                var company = document.getElementsByClassName('ee-form-company')[0].value;
                var email = document.getElementsByClassName('ee-form-email')[0].value;
                var photo = document.getElementsByClassName('ee-form-photo')[0].value;
                var phone = document.getElementsByClassName('ee-form-phone')[0].value;

                chrome.storage.sync.set({'name': name});
                chrome.storage.sync.set({'title': title});
                chrome.storage.sync.set({'company': company});
                chrome.storage.sync.set({'email': email});
                chrome.storage.sync.set({'photo': photo});
                chrome.storage.sync.set({'phone': phone},function(){
                    setTimeout(function(){window.close()},1000);
                });
            });
```

content.js (This retrieves the data from background.js in chrome.runtime)

```
var name, title, company, email, photo, phone;

    function getSignature(){
        var port = chrome.runtime.connect({name: "knockknock"});
        port.postMessage({reason: "getInfo"});
        port.onMessage.addListener(function(msg) {

            name = msg.name;
            title = msg.title;
            company = msg.company;
            email = msg.email;
            photo = msg.photo;
            phone = msg.phone;
            console.log(name + " " + title + " " + company + " " + email + " " + photo + " " + phone);

        });
    }
    getSignature();
```

Comment: Read and learn: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18699075/callback-returns-undefined-with-chrome-storage-sync-get / https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11688171/after-calling-chrome-tabs-query-the-results-are-not-available / https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14220321/how-do-i-return-the-response-from-an-asynchronous-call

Comment: Note that you can call `chrome.storage.*.get` in the content script itself.

Answer (score -1):

The variables `name, title, company, email, photo, phone` are not set up in your background.js because `chrome.storage.sync.get` is asynchronous. Instead of saving every variable in it's own object you should save them in one.

```
//setup.js
var data = {
    "name": name,
    "title": title,
    "company": company,
    "email": email,
    "photo": photo,
    "phone": phone
};
chrome.storage.sync.set({'data': data},function(){
                    setTimeout(function(){window.close()},1000);
                });

//background.js
port.onMessage.addListener(function(msg) {
      if (msg.reason == "getInfo"){
          chrome.storage.sync.get("data",function(data){
              port.postMessage(data);
          });
      }
});
```