# Undefined for chrome.storage.sync.get?

Tags: javascript, html, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

In my content script, I set a a couple `chrome.storage` values, and in my popup script, I read and get those values.

I've tried everything, but it keeps returning "undefined" which doesn't make sense because the value is certainly not undefined.

**My content.js script**:

```
imgs=["test.png","othertest.png"]

for (i = 0; i < imgs.length; i++){
    var key = "image"+i
    var value = imgs[i]
    chrome.storage.sync.set({key: value}, function() {
      console.log('Value is set to ' + value + ' and key is set to '+key);
    })
}
chrome.storage.sync.set({"count": imgs.length}, function() {
      console.log('Saved count value. Current count: '+imgs.length)
});
```

**My popup.js script**:

```
document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded',function(){
    chrome.storage.sync.get(['count'], function(result) {
        console.log(result.value)
        for (i = 0; i < result.value; i++){
            chrome.storage.sync.get(['image'+i], function(result) {
                var img = document.createElement("img")
                img.src = result.value
                document.body.appendChild(img)
            })
        }
    })
})
```

**My popup.html file**:

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
      <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <title>Untitled Document</title>
      </head>

      <body>
        <h1>Images</h1>
        <script src="popup.js"></script>
      </body>
</html>
```

The `popup.js` script is supposed to get every image from chrome.storage and display them on the popup. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Is the callback in `set` being executed?

Comment: @Royson yes. It returns `Value is set to test.png and key is set to image1`

Comment: See also [How to use a variable for a key in a JavaScript object literal?](//stackoverflow.com/q/2274242)

Answer (score 0):

**This worked for me thanks to my finding of this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18699147/8242316)!**

**Popup.js**:

```
document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded',function(){
    function getCountValue(callback) {
        chrome.storage.sync.get("count", callback);
    }
    function getImageValue(number,callback) {
        chrome.storage.sync.get(['image'+number], callback);
    }
    getCountValue(function (count) {
        for (i = 0; i < count.count; i++){
            getImageValue(i, function(imgvalue){
                for (var property in imgvalue) {
                    if (imgvalue.hasOwnProperty(property)) {
                        var img = document.createElement("img")
                        img.src = imgvalue[property]
                        document.body.appendChild(img)
                    }
                }
            })
        }
    })
})
```