# Unable to get array from chrome.storage

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension, google-chrome-devtools, google-chrome-storage

Whenever I try to get data from `chrome.storage`, it returns `undefined`.

```js
chrome.storage.sync.get('courses', function(result) {
      currentCourses = result.courses
      console.log(currentCourses)
      currentCourses.push(coursename)
      chrome.storage.sync.set({courses: currentCourses}, function() {
        alert(`Course "${coursename}" has been added !`)
      });
}
```

```js
userCourses = async () => {
  await chrome.storage.sync.get('courses', function(result) {
      return(result.courses)
  });
}
courseData = userCourses()
console.log(courseData)
```

I found an answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18699147/8115588) on stack overflow, but it is giving the same error. I am new to JS, and not comfortable with Promises.

I tried the [example](https://developer.chrome.com/docs/extensions/reference/storage/#usage) from the official docs, but it is also giving the same error as below.
Can someone help me with a solution, or modify my code ?
[image: Error]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Wrap the call to storage in a promise and await it:

```js
function getStorageValuePromise(key) {
  return new Promise((resolve) => {
    chrome.storage.sync.get(key, resolve);
  });
}

await getStorageValuePromise('val');
```

Answer (score 0):

You use `chrome.storage.sync.get()` with a completion callback. But notice that the data you retrieve using that `.get()` method isn't available except within the callback.

```js
chrome.storage.sync.get(['key'], function(result) {
  console.log('Value currently is ' + result.key);
});
```

is the example from the docs. It is the invocation of a function. But that function always and necessarily returns `undefined`.

Notice that the first parameter to `.get()` is an *array of keys*. Your code lacks the array.

The second parameter is the callback function.  It looks like this:

```js
function (result) {
   
}
```

Within the function `result.key` is the key you requested, and `result.value` is whatever you stored in the key. You're looking at `result.courses`, which isn't defined.

Control flow.

1. The call to `.get()` completes immediately, always.
2. At some later time the callback is called.